# Knockout click binding oddness in modal dialog

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

### Sample 1 - functionally broken

In this Durandal 2.0.1 view the click handlers don't fire.

```
<div class="messageBox">
  <form class="form-inline" data-bind="submit: commit">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Upload item</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <section>
        <fieldset class="main">
          ... (lots of data bound fields) ...
       </fieldset>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary button" data-bind="click: commit">OK</button>
      <button class="btn button" data-bind="click: rollback">Cancel</button>
     </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Instead, the form submit handler fires, giving no indication of which button was clicked.

### Sample 2 - visually broken

In this sample, the only difference is that the buttons are in the body div instead of the footer div. In this case, the button click handlers *do* fire, but the buttons aren't positioned correctly and the UI looks dreadful.

```
<div class="messageBox">
  <form class="form-inline" data-bind="submit: commit">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Upload item</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <section>
        <fieldset class="main">
          ... (lots of data bound fields) ...
          <button class="btn btn-primary button" data-bind="click: commit">OK</button>
          <button class="btn button" data-bind="click: rollback">Cancel</button>
        </fieldset>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In the dialog sample on the Durandal website there is an "ok" handler that is bound to both form submit and button click, as in the sample views here. It took me ages to figure out that it wasn't the button click event firing but the form submit event.

I need to put the buttons in the footer for proper layout, but I need the click events to fire so that I know whether the user clicked OK or Cancel. I can explicitly bind onclick="commit" and onclick="rollback" for the two buttons, but that's ... so hacky.

What's fouling up the binding when they're in the footer and what can I do about it?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this in a fiddle, but it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SeKkc/ - maybe could you make this break and then that would lead you to your problem? Do you need the submit binding, could you just use the click bindings themselves?

Comment: I tried your fiddle, scratched my head, removed the form submit, no change more head scratching. Commented out the "lots of inputs"... OK/Cancel start working. Uncomment inputs... OK/Cancel *continue* to work. I think I'll just go cry in a dark corner.

Comment: Maybe you have some ko comments, or similar, in the "lots of inputs" section that means that the bindings to "commit" and "rollback" are trying to fire on one of the data bound items, instead of the parent view model? See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/SeKkc/2/ - here it can't find the "commit2" and "rollback2" bindings, so it falls back to the "submit" binding instead? If so you could try "$parent.commit" which might work for you, completely depends on what structure you are binding to.

Comment: YES found it just this minute past. THIS was the culprit: <!--data-binding doesn't work with input type="file" so use change event--> when I uncommented, the actual comment turned into plaintext and stopped killing it. Post that as an answer and the points are yours, since you have pegged it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer from comments to original post:*

Normally, `click` bindings within a `submit` binding should fire correctly, as shown in this example based on the posted code: http://jsfiddle.net/SeKkc/

If you have a rogue ko comment, or some other markup that changes the binding scope, perhaps in the section marked:

> ... (lots of data bound fields) ...

This may interfere with your two bindings to `click: commit` and `click: rollback` as it may not be able to find those bindings. In other words, the `commit` function that you are attempting to bind to is accessible by the `submit: commit` binding, but something inbetween causes it to become inaccessible for the `click: commit` binding.

If the `click` binding cannot find `commit` and `rollback`, then a click on those buttons will fallback to the `submit` binding, which happens to be bound to `commit`. This fallback behaviour is shown here, where clicking the buttons will fire the `commit` function: http://jsfiddle.net/SeKkc/2/

This behaviour may also be caused by a binding to a property that does not exist on the model. The buttons are at the end of the page and are processed last. Preprocessing stops when the invalid binding is encountered; this is before the buttons are processed, so no click handler is bound to them. This is why moving them to the start of the body caused them to start working.